# How to know convexity from matrix?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given $a \in \mathbb R^3$, let $f(X) := a^T X a$. How to know whether the following minimization problem is convex or not?

$$ \min_{X \text{ is PSD}} \, f(X) $$

I know that if $f''(X) > 0$, it is convex. However, for my given function calculating $f''(X)$ gets too complicated and not straightforward. Please help.

Comment: It's somehow weird that in your definition of $f(x)$, there is no $x$ on the right hand side

Comment: Try showing the map $X \mapsto A^\top X A$ is linear. This implies convexity.

Comment: What do you mean by $f''(X)>0$?  Are you saying that $f''(X)$ is a scalar?  How are you defining it?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you have the **semidefinite program** (SDP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \langle \mathrm a \mathrm a^\top, \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_3\end{array}$$

Does this answer your question?